# Delete position in key-value list in R

Tags: r, list, key-value

Note: I'm aware that there are tons of post about basic deletion on R, but the conventional method doesnt work for this case:

Using R, I've built a key-value pair list, in which both key and value are the same string. (Might seem strange but that's a different discussion ..)

```
name <- "foo" 
list[[name]] <- name
```

Now I want to delete an element from the list again. Using the conventional method for deletion I tried:

```
list[[name]] <- NULL
```

However, this throws the following error:

```
Warning: Error in <-: more elements supplied than there are to replace
```

Does anyone know how to delete an element in a key-value list?
Cheers

Edit: Here are the relevant parts taken directly from my code

```
# saving the list element
networkName <- "Simulation_1_Run_1"
.GlobalEnv$netDynListName[[networkName]] <- (networkName)

# retrieval of the element 
# ...

# deletion of list element which causes an error
.GlobalEnv$netDynListName[[networkName]] <- NULL
```

Comment: `list[name] <- NULL`

Comment: This should work. Can you share your complete code?

Comment: Of course - just updated my post!

Comment: I get  "incompatible types (from NULL to character) in [[ assignment" from your sample code with `.GlobalEnv`. Oh but that's because I created the object as a named vector. How are you  initialising it? Works for me if I make it an empty list.